# Sistema em Django para registro de frequência dos alunos

Tags: django

Estou tentando aprender Django, mas, travei na hora de copiar dados da tabela aluno para uma tabela que registra se ele fez check-in ou check-out na escola.

[image: Como ficaria depois de pronto.]

Os alunos usarão um crachá com CPF em Código de Barras, o leitor transcreve o CPF no Campo e dar enter, o sistema busca o CPF do Aluno no banco de dados e trás as informações (até este ponto já consegui). Só que o sistema deve gravar ao mesmo tempo na tabela Check as seguintes informações (Data-hora-CPF-NOME-Status), e exibir os últimos acessos na lista na mesma página.

def busca_alunos(request):
    dados = {}

```
if check_busca:

    alunos = Aluno.objects.all()
    alunos = Aluno.objects.filter(cpf=check_busca)

else:
    alunos = Aluno.objects.all()

dados['alunos'] = alunos
return render(request, 'sistema/forms2.html', dados)
```

Como nesta mesma função copiar dados para a tabela Check e reconhecer se está fazendo Check-In ou Out. Fico grato com a ajuda de vocês!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o que eu queria, a função ficou assim:

```
def Checagem(request):
    dados = {}
    check_busca = request.GET.get('busca', None)
    checagem = Check.objects.all()
    #total = checagem.count()
    #ultimos = total - 10
    checagem = Check.objects.all().order_by('-data')[:10]
    alunos = Aluno.objects.all()

    if check_busca:
        alunos = Aluno.objects.filter(cpf=check_busca)
        check_status = Check.objects.filter(cpf=check_busca).last()
        status = check_status.status
        if status == '0':
            Check.objects.create(data=date, cpf=check_busca, nome=Aluno.objects.get(cpf=check_busca), status='1')
        else:
            Check.objects.create(data=date, cpf=check_busca, nome=Aluno.objects.get(cpf=check_busca), status='0')
        checagem = Check.objects.all().order_by('-data')[:10]
    else:
        pass
    dados['checagem'] = checagem
    dados['alunos'] = alunos

    return render(request, 'sistema/forms.html', dados)
```